# Monomials of specific degree for a polynomial.

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Let be $q,n\in \mathbb{N}$, I want to know for any $0 \leq k\leq n(q-1)$ the number of monomials with degree $k$ of the following polynomial:

$(1+x_1+\dots+ x_{1}^{q-1})\cdot(1+x_2+\dots+ x_{2}^{q-1}) \dots(1+x_n+\dots+ x_{n}^{q-1})$

I have tried to think this with multinomial coefficient. But maybe it's not the correct way to think this. Do you know any idea to help me to count it?

Comment: It looks like you want $k$ to be the total degree. Then you can put all $x_i=x$. The generating function becomes $(1-x^q)^n(1-x)^{-n}=\left(\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}x^{qr}\right)\left(\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}(-1)^s\binom{-n}{s}x^s\right)$. So, the coefficient of degree $k$ would be $\sum_{t=0}^{\lfloor k/q\rfloor}(-1)^t\binom{n}{t}(-1)^{k-qt}\binom{-n}{k-tq}$.

Comment: Hey plop, nice answer. Could you explain me, why this is the formula for degree $k$?. I understand the generating function, but It's not clear for me how to get the result.

Comment: Which part? The last step is to write down the coefficient of the [product of the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product). There are some more little simplifications that you can do, like combine the $-1$ factors, perhaps extract the negative factors from $\binom{-n}{k-qt}$.

Comment: I don't understand where it appears the ⌊/⌋. Could you explain me this please?